# Help with SamlJit Handler regarding querying total number of profile license

Tags: single-sign-on, developer-console, developer

We activated SSO in Salesforce and Azure, the users that will login to the community portal should have the license `Salesforce Platform`.

How can I query this profile license in the SamlJit Handler and check if this license runs out <= 0, it will throw an error

addError "There are no available Salesforce Platform licenses left. Please contact support." Please help if this is possible in SamlJit Handler.

Here is my SamlJit Handler:

```
    if(attributes.containsKey('User.IsActive')) {
        String IsActiveVal = attributes.get('User.IsActive');
        u.IsActive = '1'.equals(IsActiveVal) || Boolean.valueOf(IsActiveVal);
    
    if(attributes.containsKey('User.ProfileId')) {
        String profileId = attributes.get('User.ProfileId');
        System.debug('profileId' + profileId);
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name=:profileId];
        u.ProfileId = p.Id;
    } else {
        Profile p = [Select id FROM Profile WHERE Name= 'Salesforce Platform'];
    }



    //Handle custom fields here
    if(!create) {
        update(u);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  You've done a code dump here of a lot of irrelevant stuff to your issue. Please use [edit] and reduce to the bare minimum to illustrate your issue. Also -- can't you just introduce a try/catch - and let the catch block detect the out of license error that you can then post-process

Comment: see also this object that looks like it gives you what you need: [UserLicense](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm)